# Generate graph representation using PCollections in Apache Bean, Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a data source in following schema - "People ID", "Address ID". I have loaded the data into a PCollection.

Each person can have multiple address ids and each address can be allocated to multiple person. What I am trying to find is all the related peoples or people sharing same address ids not just in first level to "n" levels.

Let's say P1 have an edge to A1 and A2, P2 have an edge to A2 and A3 and P3 have an edge to A3 and A4. In this case If I draw a graph I can find that P1 is related to P2 because both share A2. And P1 is also related to P3 because P1 is related to P2 via A2 and P2 have a relation to P3 via A3.

My ultimate aim is to find this cluster of people with relationship (via Address ID). What I have done so far is trying to make use of Join.innerJoin to form the temperory table structures and loop it till whichever level we need.

```
PCollection<PeopleAddress> PA =  readEdges(); // 
PCollection<KV<String, PeopleAddress>> KAddressPA = transform(PA); // String is the address ID

PCollection<KV<String, KV<PeopleAddress, PeopleAddress>> data = Join.innerJoin(KAddressPA, KAddressPA);

//Above PCollection will give all first level edges, from this we will form a PeopleToPeople connection

PCollection<PeoplePeopleConnection> PP = getConnection(data); // From LHS and RHS we will read the ids and store. 

// With the new set of People People Connection we can  get new set of PeopleAddress edges..
Class PeoplePeopleConnection { String basePId; String cPId; }
Class PeopleAddress { String pId; String  aId; }
```

I was thinking of looping the above code n times to get the N level connections. But felt like it's little overwork. Lot of edges are duplicated. I was wondering is there any way to do it in place in PCollection. Like when we find a connection with address to an existing Person some how link it to the existing person object. Some how merge the new set of PeopleConnection or PeopleAddress connection back to a single PColleciton.

A different perspective to fix the problem ?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to separate your set of people into connected components, right? Given node A and B, if ANY path exists between them they should be grouped together. Is that correct?

Comment: How would be your output?  Something like People ID, People ID_2, Level ?

Comment: @Pablo Yes what you said was correct. I want if we can find a path between two person via Address Id. I need them to grouped together

Comment: @rmesteves Actually i don't care about the level, PeId1, PeId2 - is what I was expecting. And in the end I can just do a group by and find all the relations of PeId.

Comment: Hm do you know what's the maximum distance between two nodes? If there is no maximum distance between two nodes, this algorithm would require to iterate multiple times on a single input. || Follow up: What does your output look like? A list of connected pairs? e.g. `(P1, A1)`, `(P2, A1)`, `(P3, A1)` -> `(P1, P2)`, `(P2, P3)`, `(P3, P1)`?

Comment: I am not sure I got your questions - But I was thinking is in my code I will do a inner join Person Address tuple with another Person Addres tuple (First time both are same) joinining using the addressId. Now I can generate tuples of Person which has a relation with one jump (So if we call it 1 distance).  And  then I will form another set of tuples with P1 with all the address ids of P2.  So with the new set of relation tuple I will again start the same procedures. I will loop till N (Depth I was thinking) levels  and will produce tuples of people which have relationship distance <= N.

Comment: So for the example output I am expecting -output - (P1, P2), (P1, P3), (P2, P1), (P2, P3), (P3, P1) and (P3, P2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so up to this point, you will have pairs of people who have lived in the same address, right?

```java
PCollection<PeoplePeopleConnection> PP = getConnection(data);
```

These pairs form a graph without addresses - only people, and with `distance=1`. I like this, because it allows us to focus on the people, and discard the addresses.

So, given `(P1, P2)`, `(P2, P3)` - how do we get to also `(P1, P3)`?

We could do something like this:

```java
PCollection<KV<String, String>> twoWayPairs = PP.apply(
      FlatMapElements(pair -> Lists.of(KV.of(pair.basePId, pair.cPId), 
                                       KV.of(pair.cPId, pair.basePId))));
```

And then, we can join them, like you had before:

```java
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<String>> groupedData = twoWayPairs
            .apply(GroupByKey.create());
```

Given `(P1, P2)`, and `(P2, P3)` as input, this returns `(P2, [P1, P3])`, `(P1, [P2])`, `(P3, [P2])`. From this pair, we can derive `(P1, P3)` as the list of `distance=2` neighbors.

```java
groupedData.apply(FlatMapElements((KV<String, Iterable<String>>) neighbors -> {
    List<KV<String, String>> newPairs = cartesianProduct(neighbors.getValue());
    if (newPairs.size() == 0) {
      return Lists.of(KV.of(neighbors.getKey(), neighbors.getValue().get(0)),
                      KV.of(neighbors.getValue().get(0), neighbors.getKey()));
    } else {
      return newPairs;
    }
  });
```

Why do we check if `newPairs` is empty? Because when the `newPairs` elements is empty, then we have cases of pairs that are not linked to others (e.g. `(P1, [P2])` from earlier).

So, finally, you should be able to do something like this:

```java
// We get the distance=1 elements:
PCollection<KV<String, String>> twoWayPairs = PP.apply(
      FlatMapElements(pair -> Lists.of(KV.of(pair.basePId, pair.cPId), 
                                       KV.of(pair.cPId, pair.basePId))));

for(int i = 1; i < MAX_DISTANCE; i++) {
  twoWayPairs = twoWayPairs
      .apply(GroupByKey.create())
      .apply(FlatMapElements((KV<String, Iterable<String>>) neighbors -> {
          List<KV<String, String>> newPairs = cartesianProduct(neighbors.getValue());
          if (newPairs.size() == 0) {
              return Lists.of(KV.of(neighbors.getKey(), neighbors.getValue().get(0)),
                              KV.of(neighbors.getValue().get(0), neighbors.getKey()));
          } else {
              return newPairs;
    }
  });
}
```

This should help produce the neighbors with `distance<N`.

Consider that in this case, the data that's being shuffled increases significantly, so watch out before going to very large distance.